# How can I disable Java close comment injection in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, when I comment code in Java using the multiline comment, IntelliJ automatically closes the comment at an arbitrary line below the start of the comment. How can I disable this behaviour?

I have **unchecked every box** in **Editor > General > Smart Keys** but that didn't stop this behaviour.

I did a search for "comment" in settings and deactivated everything shown, with no luck.

Example:
Taking this simple code snippet as an example

```java
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething(List<Object> list) {
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            Object obj = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(obj.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

I add an opening of a multiline comment before the for loop to temporarily replace it with a "for each" style loop. I don't want to delete the original code before I have tested the new loop:

```java
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething(List<Object> list) {
/*
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            Object obj = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(obj.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

I position the cursor at the end of the `obj` declaration line and press "Enter" to create a new line for my closing comment. IntelliJ injects a new line with indentation and a second new line with a close multi-comment tag.

```java
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething(List<Object> list) {
/*
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            Object obj = list.get(i);

 */
            System.out.println(obj.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the injected close comment is obviously breaking the code. Sometime, that's what I want, but nearly 100% of the time, the close comment injection just breaks everything by, for example, injecting it out of sight. It's then a pain to find out what is broken in the code and why that bit of code had magically appear where it was not wanted.

**Expected result:** IntelliJ doesn't inject **anything** unless I purposely ask it to do so (with right-click, choose from the menu or keyboard shortcut).

**Actual result:** IntelliJ injects `*/` at an arbitrary line in the code, which generates compilation errors, headaches and hair lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, there is a related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141574

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that one. It's related to Java Doc comments, but they might be linked in the back-end. That kind of tells me there is no options to disable it at this point.

Comment: I looked at linked issues. That one precisely illustrate the issue I'm having:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210558
I suppose it's in IntelliJ hands now. Thanks for your help Petr

Comment: This issue was finally fixed in the latest version of IntelliJ. They added an option to disable this obnoxious behaviour.